# (Why) are line judges not instructed to delay calls to avoid interference?

Tags: tennis, officiating

The following scenario is not uncommon in tennis:

1. Player A hits the ball to Player B
2. The ball lands right on the service/back/side line
3. Almost simultaneously,
   — Player B takes the ball but misses (hits it out, the net, etc.)
   — a line judge calls the ball out on the line
4. Player A challenges the call; the challenge is successful

When this happens, the umpire usually calls a let, because there is a chance that Player B’s return was influenced by the line judge’s call – the line judge effectively interferes with the player’s stroke, and the point might have turned out differently if the line judge hadn’t made the erroneous call.

Player A usually complains about this decision (especially if it’s on a serve), arguing that it’s simply not humanly possible to react and adjust their stroke in the milliseconds between the line judge’s all and the racquet hitting the ball, and that the result would have been the same (Player B missing and losing the point) regardless of the call.

Regardless of whether that argument actually holds, it seems to me that the easiest way to avoid the situation altogether would be to instruct line judges *not to call balls out until the receiving player has completed any stroke they may be making*.

If line judges always wait just half a second before making their call, the stroke will be done, and there is no possibility of interference.

**Is this something line judges are instructed to do? And if not, why?** Are there any downsides to making the call half a second later?